# Gmail Smtp Message fails to send.

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtpclient

I'm trying to send an email using the Gmail SMTP server, but the message always fails to send. The browser window closes and Express for Web flashes with this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Code has been included below

Code Behind

```
using System.Net.Mail;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Demos_email_demo : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MailMessage myMessage = new MailMessage();
    myMessage.Subject = "Test Message";
    myMessage.Body = "Hello World";
    myMessage.From = new MailAddress("willrathlou3@gmail.com", "Will");
    myMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("willrathlou3@gmail.com", "Will"));



    SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
    mySmtpClient.Send(myMessage);


}
}
```

Web.Config

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
</system.web>
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
<smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="Will &lt;willrathlou3@gmail.com&gt;">
<network host ="smtp.gmail.com" enableSsl="true" port="465" />
</smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>
</configuration>
```

[Screenshot Of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnkQW.png)

Comment: try setting the port expicitlely in the smtp setup like this        new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)..... you may even need to use a using statement and set SSL and such like this   using (var smtp = new SmtpClient()){
            var credential = new NetworkCredential
            {
                UserName = "abc@gmail.com",  // replace with valid value
                Password = "qwerty123456"  // replace with valid value
            };
            smtp.Credentials = credential;
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtp.Port = 587;smtp.EnableSsl = true;smtp.Send(message);}

Comment: You also need to set your gmail account to allow smtp usage. https://www.google.com/search?q=set+gmail+account+to+allow+smtp&ie=&oe=

Answer (score 0):

You need to set NetworkCredential Like this.

> client.Credentials=new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

Your code should be like this.

```
    MailMessage myMessage = new MailMessage();
    myMessage.Subject = "Test Message";
    myMessage.Body = "Hello World";
    myMessage.From = new MailAddress("willrathlou3@gmail.com", "Will");
    myMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("willrathlou3@gmail.com", "Will"));

    SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
    mySmtpClient .Credentials=new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

    mySmtpClient.Send(myMessage);
```

Comment: This is definitely getting me somewhere, but Google now blocks the email being sent (even after enabling IMAP)

Comment: Allow access to less secure app in your Gmail account. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: Asp.net is now throwing the following error 'Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.'

Comment: I got it working in the end, turns out the port was set to 465. Upon setting it to 587